# What is transaction indexing in externalities useful for?

Tags: offchain-storage, host-functions

For example, there's a FRAME pallet called [Remark](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/remark) which does one thing: it allows storing data in externalities that can access the node's storage via a runtime interface. If integrated into a runtime, this would enable any user to call a signed extrinsic that stores some data off-chain. To do this, it makes use of a host function declared in `sp_io` called `transaction_index::index`.

As I understand it, it just stores an index of calls on the client's storage, which correspond to some `Option<Hash>`. This is done by `primitives::state_machine::storage_index_transaction`. What's not clear to me is that the function it calls is unimplemented:

```rust
pub trait Externalities: ExtensionStore {
    // -- snip --
    /// Index specified transaction slice and store it.
    fn storage_index_transaction(&mut self, _index: u32, _hash: &[u8], _size: u32) {
        unimplemented!("storage_index_transaction");
    }
}
```

How does transaction indexing work here and what is the intended purpose of having this?